# How to Zxing on Jdeveloper 11g

Tags: zxing, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I am using Jdeveloper 11g , and wanted to develop a barcode scanner in java, I have found Zxing thru googling and more over its opensource.

I have downloaded the Zxing-2.0.zip and found many folder for different technologies like javase, cpp, android etc, i suppose these folders are intended only for those technologies, if i want to develop in java i find two folder javase and core which have exclusive java code, but I am not sure how to use them in Jedeveloper 11g.

Can some one recommend some tutorial? Some link where I can get useful information on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build a library out of all needed jars to work with zxing and af thus to your project. Then you can start working with the zxing classes. I'm sure there are some samples on the zxing site you can refer to.